# How can I return a Promise from a catch and then reject to next catch?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a promise chain which catches an error, should perform another async operation in that catch (returning a Promise) and then should go to the last catch, but I don't know how to do this

```
const roses_color = "blue"

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (roses_color === "red") ? resolve("are") : reject("are not")
})
.then((result) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(`Roses ${result} red`), 1000)
    })
)
.catch((error) => promiseWhichWillResolve())
.then((result) => res.send(`This is true: ${result}`))
.catch((error) => res.send(`ERROR: ${error}`))
```

The output of this is

> Final result: Roses are not red

What I would like to happen instead is for the first catch to return promiseWhichWillResolve but somehow instead of that going to the last 'then' it should go to the last 'catch'.

if I just use

```
.catch((error) => {
    promiseWhichWillResolve())
    throw error
}
```

This will result in promiseWhichWillResolve not being waited for.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you cant do a `.then` after a `.catch` maybe try to modify the order of your cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized there is a real simple way to do this by using async/await in the first catch. This will ensure the async operation is completed then throw to go the last catch.

```
const roses_color = "blue"

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (roses_color === "red") ? resolve("are") : reject("are not")
})
.then((result) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(`Roses ${result} red`), 1000)
    })
)
.catch(async (error) => {
    await promiseWhichWillResolve()

    throw `Roses ${error} red`
})
.then((result) => res.send(`This is true: ${result}`))
.catch((error) => res.send(`ERROR: ${error}`))
```

Output

> ERROR: Roses are not red

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
.catch((error) => promiseWhichWillResolve().then(() => Promise.reject(error)));
```

Comment: You shouldn't nest then/catch

Comment: @RedKnight91 as you are using promiseWhichWillResolve function inside catch if it resolved with success it will enter into next then so we should cut promise chain in promiseWhichWillResolve function then